# Listview with SimpleCursorAdapter and sections

Tags: android, xml, simplecursoradapter

At the moment I have a simple list view which is feeded by a SimpleCursorAdapter. Now I want to expand the list view with a few sections. So i altered my query for my cursorAdapter and added some groupBy's.

I have looked a lot around also on Stackoverflow on how to to go on now. But I am a bit confused. How do I set up the sections? Do I need an aditional Layout.xml? Do i Need a sectionIndexer?

Please any advice / pseudo code would be helpfull.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of ListView Use Expandable ListView

Comment: Thanks very much. I got a bit further with this.